# Funcion de javascript que no funciona

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Buenas tardes a todos lo que pasa es lo siguiente tengo una función en JavaScript la cual anula copiar letras en un textbox y no funciona  tengo lo siguiente

```js
        $(function () {
            $(".numbers").keydown(function (e) {
                if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 40]) !== -1 ||
                    (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)){
                    return;
                }
                if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
         }); 
        });
```

espero que me puedan ayudar muchas gracias

Comment: capturo el textbox con <input type="number" class="form-control numbers" min="0" />

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que quiere decir que no funciona? y si tenes algo mas que aclarar en la pregunta, presiona el boton [edit] y edita la pregunta. y otra cosa, ninguno de esos tags que pusiste tiene que ver con la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues no veo cual es el problema. He recreado el código que has mandado y a mi me funciona bien... Podría ser que te falte incluir la librería de JQuery.

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="number" class="form-control numbers" min="0" />
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
        $(".numbers").keydown(function (e) {
            if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 40]) !== -1 ||
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)){
                return;
            }
            if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
     }); 
    });
</script>
```